# Implementing lazy loading in homepage posts instead of pagination

Tags: jquery, javascript

I have lots of posts in [my website](http://blog.kushaljoshi.com.np). I have used `default pagination` function for paging the post list in *homepage*. But I wanted to implement `lazy loading` instead of pagination just like in *twitter*. I don't have any idea about it's implementation in *Wordpress*.

Please help me with this.

Comment: can you share your solution for this problem

Comment: well i had to change the some code in js file . . Tell me where you have been paused . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [**Infinite Scroll**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/infinite-scroll/) plugin which Automatically append the next page of posts (via AJAX) to your page when a user scrolls to the bottom.

Comment: But i have some complication still left to be removed :((. I am having problem in the end of the list. When the posts end up the plugin shows the contents of 404 error page. Can you advise me how to check the end of the post list so that it would be easier for me to display the posts until the last post remain? ?

Comment: thats beacuse you 404 page  is set to return something other then 404 - page not found. Take a look at the documentation http://www.infinite-scroll.com

Comment: Yea  . . I got some code modification in js file . . Anyways, thanks for the suggestion:))